# Can innobackupex --apply-log operation can be run on target machine

Tags: mysql, innobackupex

I am using innobackupex tool for hot backup on mysql. I am taking backup through --stream option. My main question is that can i use --apply-log operation on remote machine after data is transferred to remote location or else should i use --apply-log operation only on source db machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer through this url

http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/07/btw-xtrabackup-is-not-only-backup/

WE can run apply-log anywhere once backup is taken

Thanks